# Is leaflet package doesn't work in shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny

```
enter code here
```

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)


ui <- fluidPage(
    leafletOutput("m", height=800)
)


server <- function(input, output, session){
    
    output$m <- renderLeaflet({
        
        leaflet() %>% 
            addTiles() %>% 
            setView(lng = 126.97806, lat=37.56667, zoom=13)
        
        acci <- read.csv("C:/Users/mitri/OneDrive/Desktop/Shiny Project/accidents.csv")
        
        m <- leaflet(acci) %>% 
            setView(lng = 126.97806, lat=37.56667, zoom=13) %>% 
            addTiles() %>%
            addCircles(lng=~경도, lat=~위도, color=~acci_colour(사고유형구분), radius=20, 
                       popup=paste0("<br>사고장소:",acci$사고지역위치명, "<br>발생건수:", acci$발생건수,
                                    "<br>사상자수:", acci$사상자수, "<br>사망자수:", acci$사망자수,
                                    "<br>중상자수:", acci$중상자수, "<br>경상자수:", acci$경상자수,
                                    "<br>부상자수:", acci$부상자수)) %>% 
            addLegend(position = "bottomleft",
                      title = "사고유형",
                      pal = acci_colour, values = ~사고유형구분, opacity = 1)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then, I get this error message :
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 3199282...DONE
Deploying bundle: 3840435 for application: 3199282 ...
Waiting for task: 821153808
building: Processing bundle: 3840435
building: Installing packages
building: Installing files
building: Pushing image: 4361485
deploying: Starting instances
rollforward: Activating new instances
success: Stopping old instances
Application successfully deployed to https://project-lht.shinyapps.io/Project1/
Deployment completed: https://project-lht.shinyapps.io/Project1/
����޽���(��):
In fileDependencies.R(file) :
Failed to parse C:/Users/mitri/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpEvBQ16/file1ba046ab5b1a/app.R ; dependencies in this file will not be discovered.

and

https://project-lht.shinyapps.io/Project1/?_ga=2.71535259.944162847.1604971501-1361677912.1604971501

Comment: If you put your file in the app folder, it will be deployed with your app

Comment: You can try deploying the [first example](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html) to make sure everything is ok

Comment: I already tried.. but T^T

Comment: That first example works fine when [deployed from my environment](https://hleviel.shinyapps.io/testapp/)